# Filtering addresses of output of google maps search whisperer by country

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Is possible in google autocomple make whisperer for addresses which are only from one country?
So when you start writing in search box it will give (whisper) you only addresses from one specific country?

Comment: [Restrict the search to a specific country](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [componentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ComponentRestrictions) of the Places library:

```
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'de' // ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code, case insensitive
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.